# Insert New Line After X Amount Of Periods

Tags: notepad++

Can someone please tell me what command would I need to type to have Notepad++ create a new paragraph after X amount of periods?

For example, I want take a large block of text and have Notepad++ create a blank line after every 5 periods which will essentially turn that one paragraph into multiple smaller ones.

I've searched for hours but can't find the solution anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to create a new paragraph after every 5 sentences.

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(.*?)\. (.*?)\. (.*?)\. (.*?)\. (.*?)\.`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1. \2. \3. \4. \5.\r\n\r\n`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

If you don't want the blank lines between the paragraphs remove one of the `\r\n` from "Replace with".

[image]

**Before**:

> Morbi ultrices placerat nulla, quis dapibus justo dignissim eget. Etiam erat tellus, aliquam at vulputate a, maximus at ipsum. Ut mollis enim nec nibh porta, et ornare augue vulputate. Maecenas quis tortor sed sapien semper consequat. Proin mollis arcu neque, at aliquet est bibendum vel. Suspendisse ac erat eget justo imperdiet eleifend at molestie sapien. Nullam ac eros urna. Quisque dictum mauris eget ligula scelerisque, a consectetur ante posuere. Donec cursus libero id nisl aliquam, consectetur facilisis mi ultrices. Aliquam interdum tempor arcu eu porttitor. Pellentesque sagittis, eros vel condimentum consequat, felis sapien rutrum lectus, efficitur mattis justo nisl nec sapien.

**After**:

> Morbi ultrices placerat nulla, quis dapibus justo dignissim eget. Etiam erat tellus, aliquam at vulputate a, maximus at ipsum. Ut mollis enim nec nibh porta, et ornare augue vulputate. Maecenas quis tortor sed sapien semper consequat. Proin mollis arcu neque, at aliquet est bibendum vel.
>
> Suspendisse ac erat eget justo imperdiet eleifend at molestie sapien. Nullam ac eros urna. Quisque dictum mauris eget ligula scelerisque, a consectetur ante posuere. Donec cursus libero id nisl aliquam, consectetur facilisis mi ultrices. Aliquam interdum tempor arcu eu porttitor.
>
> Pellentesque sagittis, eros vel condimentum consequat, felis sapien rutrum lectus, efficitur mattis justo nisl nec sapien.

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ click on search
click on replace

in the replace dialog box, in the left corner you will see Search Mode section.
Check "Extended"

In the find what box type in the number of periods you want to use, and in the replace with box enter \r\n for the carriage return code (a.k.a line break). This will replace the X amount of periods with a carriage return.

IF you don't want to lose the periods, but just add the line breaks you would add the X number of periods before the \r\n in the replace box.

[image: replace dialogue box]

have a great day,

mc

Comment: Just a small addition. Ctrl+h opens this window on the Replace tab directly. BTW, this Ctrl+h works in most text editors/word processors

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts are so much faster, thanks for that one.  Long ago it used to simply be f3...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment but unfortunately that did not work for me.